# Trying to open .txt file from a program in bin folder (Mac)

Tags: c, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to open a .txt file from a program in my bin directory but I'm not sure what search path it uses to find folders.  I'm using fopen in my program to open these files.  I've tried several paths but it doesn't seem to work:

```
char path[80] = "../Users/MyName/Desktop/Folder/";
char path[80] = "Users/MyName/Desktop/Folder/";
char path[80] = "Folder/";
char path[80] = "";
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use absolute path:`char path[80] = "/Users/MyName/Desktop/Folder/"`, or use `getcwd` to get current working directory, then use relative path, or use `chdir` to change working directory to the directory you want to access, then open the file.